# How to integrate SAP software and SharePoint via SAP PI?

Tags: sharepoint, integration, sap-pi, sap-xi

I am not familiar with SAP software, but my latest project is to combine some SAP software and SharePoint Portal via SAP PI. SAP PI will be used to automate the data flow between some other SAP software and the SharePoint Portal...

I didn't find enough valuable information on the web.

Could someone give me ideas on this, or tell me where I could find this kind of information?

Answer (score 2):

here are a couple of choices available to you with respect to SharePoint to SAP integration but a lot of it depends on what you want to drive the data. Will it be something already in SP and drive that into SAP or is there a process or data method in SAP that you want to expose in SP?

There are a number of different approaches to doing this, in no particular order I list the approaches that you might wish to consider.

- Development effort heavy customization of your SP and SAP environment to force integration
- Prebuilt scenario implementation - involves installation of 3rd party software and configuration of SAP & SP
- SAP's out-of-the-box limited approach to SP integration
- A build your own approach - involves minimal SAP changes but allows you to expose access to SAP on SP and vise versa

Key Players in this space are Winshuttle and SAP & Microsoft's collaboration intitative called Duet

Recommended Reading

- http://wiki.sdn.sap.com/wiki/display/Community/SAP+and+SharePoint+Integration
- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261738(v=office.12).aspx

You will also find a good read on the advantages and disadvantages of all approaches by reading Vikram Chalana's blog post on the WInshuttle community site. SImply type ***Approaches to SharePoint and SAP Integration chalana*** into google search to find this.

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on what you want to do.

Maybe additionally to the other answer:

S/4 HANA Cloud Essentials 2120 has build in support for SharePoint and other DMS as file storage for documents etc (I did not work with it but probably you have to customize a bit).

If it is less on file but on information level, S/4 HANA has some OData APIs that you can use and an Enterprise Messaging Socket that u can use together with PI or CPI to extract data and send it to the Sharepoint API.